# RTOS Alongside Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel, rtos

I have a question about a family of softwares, of which one example is [INtime](http://www.tenasys.com/index.php/tenasys-products/intime-rtos-family/intime-for-windows), which lets you run a real-time operating system in parallel with Windows.

I have a reasonable grasp on how Windows works, including kernel/driver/application security rings etc.  Similarly, I know how a RTOS runs on a dedicated system.

The Simple Question:
How do these go about existing together without fighting over hardware or other similar problems?  How is the allocation or resources made, and how is this integrated with Windows?

Slightly more complicated:

What are the steps I would have to take if I wanted to develop something similar myself?  Are there some open-source embodiment's of this paradigm I can inspect to glean some more understanding?

Comment: I am sure that the vendor will be glad to explain it to you.  In fact the site you linked to does exactly that.  It runs on a separate core, I/O is allocated to the RTOS or Windows, not both.

Comment: Thanks @Clifford.  Your comments led me to clarify my question space a bit.